# Swift tabBar not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, menu, tabs, uikit

In Xcode I have this app that uses tabBarItem. There are 5 items and occasionally when I'm on a specific page I get this weird overlay of the tabBarItems (see pictures). I say occasionally, because it does not do it always but it is still very frequent. Not sure if it is just a limitation with tabBarItem or if I have a bug.

This is how it SHOULD look:
[image]

This is how it SHOULD NOT look, but does:
[image]

As you can see in the second image the tabBar is being overlayed onto the other text rather than disappearing behind it. It's odd that it behaves differently for each tab.

I can fix the issue with

```
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .black
            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance
        }
```

But need a fix that would work for IOS 11+

Answer (score -1):

```
        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
```